# add JMenuBar to JPanel

Tags: java, jpanel, jmenubar

I cannot add a `JMenuBar` to a `JPanel`.

My code is as follows:

```
public class MyClass extends JPanel
{
      public MyClass ()
      {
              JMenuBar b = new JMenuBar();
              add(b);
              b.add(new JMenu("Menu"));
              ...
       }
}
```

Comment: What does it do ? What do you expect it does ?

Comment: JToolBar might be a better option

Comment: Hello Pierre, I want a JMenuBar on top of my JPanel

Comment: JToolBar could be an option, although I want my JMenuBar to be completely independent and separated form my JPanel, and it seems I cannot do this with JToolBar

Comment: You can't add a JMenuBar to a JPanel.  You can only add a JMenuBar to a JFrame with the setJMenuBar method.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem("Item1");
bar.add(item);//item menu
add(bar); // ad to panel
```

if you want to position themselves could use an example design [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html)

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
add(bar, BorderLayout.NORTH);//position menu
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does nothing in my class. Besides my class already extends JPanel, so I think there's no need to create a new JPanel.